# Como criar um despertador com mozilla notifications

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo uma agenda em JSP, a agenda já está totalmente pronta, faltando apenas avisar um despertador que estou querendo fazer, o mesmo deve funcionar da seguinte maneira..

De x tempo antes dos eventos marcados com "lembrar-me" quero enviar uma notificação para o usuário.. Exemplo: Evento as 19:00, quando for 18:45 quero enviar uma mensagem: "Faltam 15 minutos para o seu evento X."

Pelo que pesquisei eu consigo fazer isso utilizando mozilla notifications: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/WebAPI/Alarme

Alguém já fez algo parecido, sabe utilizar mozilla notifications junto com essa questão da hora?

Obrigado

Comment: Fernando, a `API` de Alarme funciona apenas no `Mozilla Firefox`, uma alternativa é utilizar a [`Push API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API), esta é suportada pelo `Firefox`, `Chrome` e `Opera`, porém você terá de enviar a notificação do seu Servidor, a vantagem é que a mesma funciona mesmo com a pagina esteja fechada.

Comment: Parece bom.. Vou pesquisar e se isso solucionar meu problema coloco como ficou aqui.. Obrigado pela ideia

Comment: Infelizmente isso não resolve minhas dúvidas.. Na verdade apenas  substitui o uso do mozilla notifications, ainda preciso de uma forma  de estipular os horários para elas aparecerem...